# Laravel can not select longblob from table

Tags: database, laravel, select, blob

I have a table which has a longblob field, when I run the following query where `dokument` is the blob, I get no dump. On select other fields everything is fine

```
$blobs = \DB::table('dokumente')->select('dokument')->get();
dd($blobs);
```

What can be the reason how to debug this issue,

Answer (score 0):

Can you include the schema for this database, along with the print out from dd($blobs)

The only think I can think of without that information is that the field dokument does not exist and the code is throwing an error.

A simple table with a Longblob field i get this for a DD

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#789
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => {#790
      +"dokument": "RANDOM STRING"
   }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use select, write column in get method call